# Do Scotchlok connectors meet code?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Just bought a log home built in 1980. Doing some remodeling /updating. Almost all the junction boxes have 3M Scotchlok in them. Sometimes they are referred to as "vampire connectors."

Are these connectors up to code? I'm thinking of taking them all out and using the standard twist wire connectors.

The connectors are sized properly. For example, the kitchen outlets are on a 20 amp circuit with 12 gauge wire. The Scotchlok connector model used is 562. Looking on the connector it says "10-12 GA". Looking online I found the product sheet and it is UL 486C compliant as well (not sure that meets the NEC code for wiring a home).

I'm used to seeing these used in car audio stuff... Not in the home. And they usually end up having problems... Like not making a good connection, or failing altogether.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I checked the spec on the Scotchlok 562 tap connectors. They are UL listed for solid and stranded wire and rated at 600 volts.  I have seen them used in manufactured housing before, but rarely.  Here are the [manufacturers specifications](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/p/d/b5005048014/) for this product.

Comment: I updated your dead link. Not sure if it's what you intended, but it seems to contradict your answer.

Comment: @isherwood -- the linked spec sheet says different things about voltage rating in different places; however, UL lists the 562 in it's [ZMVV.E23438 file for 3M's connectors](https://iq.ulprospector.com/en/profile?e=1253049) (link requires (free) account on UL Product iQ) though, so you're safe using them

Answer (score 1):

Car audio ? Thought that would more be solder and heatshrink or crimps?

Well they are commonly and reliably used for telephone cabling. Don't see many issues with them in that application.

Also tend to see them for irrigation solenoids and same story.

If anything wire nuts are frowned upon in other parts of the world.

Answer (score -2):

No,  these are NOT to code for household electrical use. Don't use these. You're only allowed to use twist on wire nuts or a "push on"  wire nut (I forget the proper name of them,  but they are considerably more expensive compared to traditional wire nuts)

Comment: The Scotchlok "vampire taps" are UL listed in the same category ZMVV as every UL listed wire nut on the planet...so Code can't tell the difference either.